# Swift: Provide default value inside string literal

Tags: swift, option-type, string-literals

I'm going to provide a default value for an optional String which is placed inside a String literal as a parameter (if I've used the right keywords!). 
I want to know how can I set a default value for it using "??" operator?

I think I should use escape characters before double quote but I don't know what is the right syntax.
Here is my syntax which lead to error:

```
print ("Error \(response.result.error ?? "default value") ")
//------------------------ what should be ^here^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This should be correct, provided `result.error` is really `String?`.

Comment: @Sulthan Good point. I assumed so for my answer (not necessarily a string, but definitely an optional)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap it in parentheses:

```
print("Error \((response.result.error ?? "default value"))")
```

The cleaner way is to use @Alladinian answer and put the string in a variable before printing it

Answer (score 3):

You have to *literally* substitute `default value` with your message.

No need to escape double quotes since you're inside `\(<expression>)` (More about Swift's string interpolation [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html))

If you need a cleaner approach then do it in two steps:

```
let msg = response.result.error ?? "whatever"
print("Error: \(msg)")
```

Finally, if you want to print only non-nil errors (avoiding logs for responses that did not produce any errors) you could do:

```
if let error = response.result.error { print("Error: \(error)") }
```